# Tensorflow 'IndexedSlices' object has no attribute 'get_shape' during backprop through while_loop

Tags: tensorflow

I'm experimenting with writing my own `dynamic_rnn()` function. However I'm getting the following error when initialising my model:

```
AttributeError: 'IndexedSlices' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

It's to do with calculating gradients. Here is the full stack trace (nb. it happens even if I remove the gradient clip - it just moves to the optimizer).

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c4ed7a228363> in <module>()
----> 1 model = Model(args)

<ipython-input-5-2ab152ab1152> in __init__(self, args, infer)
     58 
     59         tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
---> 60         grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(self.cost, tvars),
     61                 args.grad_clip)
     62         optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr) # tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.lr) #

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.pyc in gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method)
    479                 # pylint: enable=protected-access
    480               else:
--> 481                 in_grads = _AsList(grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
    482               _VerifyGeneratedGradients(in_grads, op)
    483               if gate_gradients and len(

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_grad.pyc in _EnterGrad(op, grad)
    184   if op.get_attr("is_constant"):
    185     # Add a gradient accumulator for each loop invariant.
--> 186     result = grad_ctxt.AddBackPropAccumulator(grad)
    187   else:
    188     result = exit(grad)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.pyc in AddBackPropAccumulator(self, value)
   1430     """
   1431     self.Exit()
-> 1432     shape = value.get_shape()
   1433     if not shape.is_fully_defined():
   1434       shape = None

AttributeError: 'IndexedSlices' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

I've identified the problem as something in my `while_loop`. If I add `backprop=False` as an argument to the `while_loop` function everything is fine. Below is the relevant code.

```
inputs = array_ops.transpose(self.input_data, [1, 0])
input_shape = array_ops.shape(inputs)
(time_steps, batch_size) = array_ops.unpack(input_shape, 2)
time = array_ops.constant(0, dtype=dtypes.int32, name="time")
state = self.initial_state

# TensorArrays
base_name = scope

output_ta = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
    dtype=dtypes.float32, size=time_steps,
    tensor_array_name=base_name + "output")

input_ta = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
    dtype=inputs.dtype, size=time_steps,
    tensor_array_name=base_name + "input")

input_ta = input_ta.unpack(inputs)

# Step function
def _take_step(cur_time, output_ta_t, cur_state):
    inps = input_ta.read(cur_time)
    step_inps = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, inps)
    step_inps = tf.reshape(step_inps,[-1,self.input_embedding_size])
    output, new_state = self.cell((step_inps, attention), cur_state)
    output_ta_t = output_ta_t.write(cur_time, output)
    variable_scope.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    return (cur_time + 1, output_ta_t, new_state)

# Tensor while_loop
final_loop_vars = control_flow_ops.while_loop(
      cond=lambda t, *_: t < time_steps,
      body=_take_step,
      loop_vars=(time, output_ta, state),
      parallel_iterations=None,
      swap_memory=False)
```

As much as possible I've tried to copy the code from `dynamic_rnn()`. Though I have simplified it a bit for my particular use case.

I'm not sure what part of the code is creating an `IndexedSlices` object. So I'm having trouble working out where to start debugging.

Comment: Maybe a bigger stack trace?? IndexedSlices is used for sparse gradients. Do you have sparse variables, as inputs, perhaps? Can you print the name of the variable? That could help to understand where it comes from in your graph.

Comment: I added the full stack trace. It just goes back to the optimizer and unfortunately doesn't tell me any more information about where the error is. Similarly it's not providing a name for the `IndexedSlices`. I haven't purposely used any sparse variables anywhere.

Comment: @drpn that said I am using a softmax cross entropy function. Specifically the one (slightly modified) from `seq2seq` which uses `nn_ops.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logit, target)`. Any chance the problem could be there?

Comment: Ah, yes, that could be the problem. That function uses sparse logits, whereas the regular softmax uses dense.